# Bamboo and Visual Studio Test Agent

Tags: visual-studio-2015, continuous-integration, bamboo

I've set up an instance of Bamboo today to enable CI support. Since I'm mainly a .NET developer, I've been looking for ways to set it up.

Stuff I've installed:

- MSBuild
- Visual Studio Test Agent 2015 (includes MSTest.exe - which is basically all you should need)

I've created a Bamboo task and added a GIT checkout and MSBuild task. So far so good.

Now, I want to execute all MS unit tests in a given test DLL. However, so far I've been unable to configure that.

I've added an 'MSTest Runner' and attempted to select my Visual studio folder ( Add new executable -> Add name -> click 'Add' -> No response..).

Q: What's the proper way to get this up and running?

PS: Note that VS2015 Test Agent is free (and contains all the necessary tools, and is light-weight), while installing a VS2015 instance might have licensing issues. Basically this thing is created for CI tasks, so I might as well use it for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add new executable, then you can add them to server capabilities also . Go to Agents->Capabilities->Add Capabilty. Then select capability type as Executable and fill other two required fields. (Key and Value)
Key can be any name and Value should be path where executable MSTest.exe is located.  This document https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO059/MSTest+Runner might be helpful.

Comment: That did it; now it pops up.